Rust Ownership and Borrowing
fn main(){
    let mut example = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
}
fn func(example: &mut Vec<i32>){
    for num in example{
        println!("{}", num);
    }
    println!("{:?}", example);
}


An implicit iterator "Into_iter" is used, which occurs after the loop has completed. Does an iterator return data back to a vector? Because if you specify it explicitly, the code works, but if not, then the error “example moved due to this implicit call to .into_iter()” will appear. If you can, tell us point by point the rules of ownership and borrowing. So that I understand why this happens
fn main(){
    let mut example = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
}
fn func(example: &mut Vec<i32>){
    for num in example.into_iter(){
        println!("{}", num);
    }
    println!("{:?}", example);
}


Considering that IntoIterator is implemented for Vec<T>, &Vec<T>, and &mut Vec<T> (docs), I'm guessing something weird is going on with auto deref.

that is, you don’t know the answer?

for num in &mut *example{
Iwhere an error disappears when you explicitly dereference and add a new link within a loop. This only happens with implicit conversion.

Yeah my guess was wrong. I experimented with impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut MyType (without an impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a MyType) and saw the same thing. Very interesting.

The desugaring of the for-loop is not r.into_iter(), it's IntoIterator::into_iter(r). If you try that in the second example, you get the same error as the first. It appears to be a case where implicit reborrowing doesn't work, so you have to do in &mut *example. Not posting as an answer because I can't really explain why this is.

I don't know, maybe some compiler magic happens, and it not gets passed as &mut *example in the for loop.

"Does an iterator return data back to a vector?" - iterating over a &mut Vec yields mutable references to the elements. I.e. the data never moves to begin with.
